# DESeq2 "NA values are not allowed" error when any(is.na(counts)) = FALSE

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a count matrix that had NA values in it.

I set them to 0 using

```
counts[is.na(counts)] <- 0
```

Which then successfully sets them to 0 and I can see this.

But then when I try to use

```
DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(counts, colData = data.frame(colnames(counts)), design = ~1)
```

I get the error

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “DESeqDataSet” object: NA values are not allowed in the count matrix
```

Which seems pretty clear but I don't understand because I set all NA values to 0 and now if I do

```
any(is.na(counts))
```

I get FALSE.

Any help is greatly appreciated thankyou!

Comment: most likely something weird in your matrix. Can you do ```dput(head(counts,5))``` and paste the output? or do a ```str(counts)``` and paste that

Comment: This is the first few lines
structure(list(SP106993 = c(74, 321312, 96207, 1586388, 50827
), SP106998 = c(1770, 12251235, 2546624, 1129265, 166216), SP107004 = c(1491, 
5559611, 1739052 ...

Comment: And for str(counts)
 str(LIRIJPRawCounts)
'data.frame': 22913 obs. of  445 variables:
 $ SP106993: num  74 321312 96207 1586388 50827 ...
 $ SP106998: num  1770 12251235 2546624 1129265 166216 ...
 $ SP107004: num  1491 5559611 1739052 2319073 155238 ...

Comment: Do you need all of the lines?

Comment: seems like you have a data.frame but thats ok, ```table(sapply(data.frame(counts),class))``` , all are numeric?

Comment: Yes numeric 
    445

Comment: Oh wait there is more to the error than I first noticed: 
NAs introduced by coercion to integer rangeError in validObject(.Object) : 
     invalid class “DESeqDataSet” object: NA values are not allowed in the count matrix

Comment: You have infinite values. check, ```counts[rowSums(is.infinite(counts))>0,]```

Comment: This is very weird, when I do is.infinite(counts) I get the error message: 
`Error in is.infinite(LIRIJPRawCounts) : 
 default method not implemented for type 'list'.` 
It works when I do 'is.infinite(as.matrix(counts))' but doing `any(is.infinite(as.matrix(counts)))` returns FALSE and doing the code you said with `as.matrix()`  returns an empty dataframe with just the colnames

Comment: `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(as.matrix(counts), colData = data.frame(colnames(counts)), design = ~1)` returns the same NA values are not allowed in the count matrix error message

Comment: can you do, ```cts = as.matrix(counts) ; cts[is.infinite(cts) | is.na(cts)] = 0 ; DESeqData(..)```

Comment: Yeah this gives me the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223701/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-jack-henry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have NAs, it should work.

```
library(DESeq2)

counts = matrix(rnbinom(1000,mu=50,size=1),100,10)
colnames(counts) = paste0("c",1:10)
counts[sample(length(counts),10)] = NA
counts[is.na(counts)] <- 0

DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(counts, colData = data.frame(colnames(counts)), design = ~1)
```

If you have infinite values, it gives you a slightly different error:

```
counts = matrix(rnbinom(1000,mu=100,size=1),100,10)
colnames(counts) = paste0("c",1:10)
counts[1] = 2.5e9

DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(counts, colData = data.frame(colnames(counts)), design = ~1)
```

It looks like this:

```
converting counts to integer mode
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “DESeqDataSet” object: NA values are not allowed in the count matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In mde(x) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Error comes about because you cannot convert the large numbers to integer:

```
max(counts)
[1] 8007375876

as.integer(max(counts))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

And this is smaller than the maximum allowed:

```
.Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
```

For analysis purpose, since you are more interested in the difference between genes, one way is to scale the matrix down

```
DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(round(counts/2), colData = data.frame(colnames(counts)), design = ~1)
```